# Solr payloads: count terms with highest payload value

Tags: solr

Imagine we have these documents in solr

```
{id: 1, values: [foo|0.7, bar|0.3] }
{id: 2, values: [foo|0.6, bar|0.3] }
{id: 3, values: [foo|0.2, bar|0.4] }
```

What I want to get as a result is counts of terms but only account one term per document, the one with the highest payload value, so result is:

```
foo: 2
bar: 1
```

Because for doc with id = 1 `foo` has highest payload value, for id = 2 again `foo` has highest payload value and for id = 3 `bar` has the highest payload value.

How would I get this?

Comment: I think precalculating that value would be by far the most efficient, instead of having to iterate through all payloads and keep a count for each payload value